# Unable to access property of UITableView subclass

Tags: swift, mocking, tdd

I am trying to test whether the method ReloadData() is called by an instance of UITableView when it's dataSource is updated.

I've created a subclass of UITableView called MockTableView. It has a bool called reloadDataGotCalled which is set to true when the overridden function reloadData() is called. I then try access that property from within my test class to test whether it is true.

However when I try to do so the compiler gives me the message that "Value of type 'UITableView' has no member 'reloadDataGotCalled'"

I'm not sure why it's doing that, because as far as I can see I've set that value to be of the type 'MockTableView' which should have that member?

// A ViewController that contains a tableView outlet that I want to test.

```
class ItemListViewController: UIViewController {

    let itemManager = ItemManager()

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var dataProvider: (UITableViewDataSource & UITableViewDelegate & ItemManagerSettable)!

    @IBAction func addItem(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if let nextViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "InputViewController") as? InputViewController {
            nextViewController.itemManager = itemManager
            present(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = dataProvider
        tableView.delegate = dataProvider
        dataProvider.itemManager = itemManager
    }

}
```

// My test class

```
class ItemListViewControllerTest: XCTestCase {

    var sut: ItemListViewController!

    override func setUp() {
        //Given
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ItemListViewController")
        sut = (viewController as! ItemListViewController)
        //When
        sut.loadViewIfNeeded()
        }
```

// The test where I'm trying to assign sut.tableView to mockTableView

```
func test_TableView_IsReloadedWhenItemAddedToItemManger() {
        let mockTableView = MockTableView()
        sut.tableView = mockTableView
        let item = ToDoItem(title: "Foo")
        sut.itemManager.add(item)
        sut.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: true)
        sut.endAppearanceTransition()
        XCTAssertTrue(sut.tableView.reloadDataGotCalled) // <- this is where I'm getting the compiler message "Value of type 'UITableView' has no member 'reloadDataGotCalled'"
    }

}
```

// My mockTableView subclass in an extension of the ItemListViewControllerTests

```
extension ItemListViewControllerTest {

    class MockTableView: UITableView {

        var reloadDataGotCalled = false

        override func reloadData() {
            super.reloadData()
            reloadDataGotCalled = true
        }
    }

}
```

I'm expecting that it should compile, and then the test should fail because I've not written the code to make it pass yet?

Comment: uitableview does not have that variable, only `MockTableView` has it

Comment: Thank you for answering. How come I'm not able to access that variable despite setting sut.tableView to be an instance of MockTableView()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined **tableView** instance in **ItemListViewController** as **UITableView**. So, you can't access the **MockTableView**'s property with that instance.

You can only access the parent's properties from the children not the vice versa. If you still want to access the property you can try something like the snippet below.

```
XCTAssertTrue((sut.tableView as! MockTableView).reloadDataGotCalled)
```

Hope it helps.